# search word which should present at start of words in another string using python

Tags: python, keyword-search

I am trying to search list of word in another string.
I use below code

```
>>> word='abc present'
>>> each='abctotech present'    
>>> (all(x in each.split() for x in word.split()))
False
```

In above I am getting result as "False" but "abc" word is initial part of one word in string each which is "abctotech"

Is there another way which I can use to return "True" value for above scenario.
Please advice.

Comment: @hansolo, Thanks a lot for your reply, it worked for given scenario, but if I change string each to " each='toabctotech present'  " still it is printing results as "True", I want to search word if it's present at start of words available in another string

Comment: Use the list as result for `all` instead of the generator: `all([ x in each for x in word.split() ])`

Comment: @hansolo, Thank you very much. Your suggestion works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check `any` of the `strings` in `each` starts with the one in `words` like,

```
>>> each
'abctotech present'
>>> word
'abc present'
>>> all(any(y.startswith(x) for y in each.split()) for x in word.split())
True
>>> each1
'toabctotech present'
>>> all(any(y.startswith(x) for y in each1.split()) for x in word.split())
False
```